# Which hypothesis testing should I use for pageview/user during ab test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, ab-test

I am currently running an experiment on a website, there are control and 1 variant. The variant changes one of the features of the website.

Besides calculating the click-through-rate(CTR) of that feature, I also want to understand the impact on pageviews/users, pageview/sessions etc. Most of the users only browse 1 to 2 pages and never come back, only few of them will revisit. So I suppose the distribution of pageviews/users will not be normal, but more like a right-skewed distribution.

Most of the materials about ab testing  focuses on CTR, so I am confused how should I deal with other metrics like pageviews/users etc.

Comment: Your question is very general. The book *Trustworthy Online Controlled Experiments: A Practical Guide to A/B Testing* by Kohavi, Tang, and Xu has lots of advice.

Comment: Please spell out your abbrevs!